# Dynamically added EditText is not editable

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an adapter class and inside the getView() method, I am dynamically creating a EditText like below:

```
@Override
public View getView(final S data, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView,
                AdapterView adapter, int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
View view = super.getView(data, convertView, parentView, adapter, position);
if (view == null) return view;
Context context = view.getContext();
final EditText editText = new EditText(context);
```

}

I am returning same EditText based on some conditions. EditText is visible but it is not editable. I tried using

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

But it gives focus to one editText only, after getting out of focus from that edittext, it is not getting focused and so not editable.

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What does this focus to one editText only specifies?

Comment: Same edittext is used to show edittext in the view based on different conditions

Comment: Try inflating one instead, it might solve the problem.